# Iterative approach to solving steady state equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In the context of solving the steady-state heat equation $f_{xx} = 0$ in one space dimension using, one approach that can be used is to use the heat equation $f_{xx} = f_t$, separate are input domain into little intervals (finite difference method) and iteratively update $f$ by little $t$ time steps.

More formally, for the boundary condition $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, we can separate the $[0, 1]$ interval into points $x_i = \frac{i}{n}$, set $f_1(x_i) = 0$ as an initial guess for $i \in \{1,..,n\}$, and then update $f_{n+1}(x_i) = g(f_{n}(x_{i-1}), f_{n}(x_{i}), f_{n}(x_{i+1}))$, where $g$ is an estimate of $f_{xx}$.

This will converge to the steady state heat equation, and has the simple physical intuition that as heat diffuses, the temperature state will reach a steady state.

However, I cannot easily see whether some arbitrary differential equation like e.g. $f_{x} + f_{xxx} = 0$ has a corresponding physical interpretation, and thus whether it would make sense to try to solve $f_{x} + f_{xxx} = 0$ as if we can assume that $f_{x} + f_{xxx} = \pm f_t$, and again making little time steps.

//

Is there any way to describe the conditions under this approach works? It could be said that if such a method converges, then it converges to a solution of the equation $f_{x} + f_{xxx} = 0$, but that's really just rephrasing the condition that $f_t=0$... so it seems to me like there's more to it than just that - there's something interesting about the fact that we're looking for a solution of an equation, and at the same time, its current value is exactly what we need to get closer to that solution.

Comment: With the heat equation you follow approximately the same way as taking any fixed-point equation, interpret it as forward-Euler method, derive the underlying differential equation and solve that with possibly some other ODE integrator. The main point is to get to the fixed-point equation, and to get a convergent iteration. For the second derivative you get a (slightly) diagonally dominant matrix, so that applying the Jacobi-iteration or any relaxation of it gives a good iteration. For the second case you have to get inventive.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry, I don't quite follow, but that's my mistake... I know my question is very vague. My question is really this - if one were to not know any physics, but they were interested in how to solve $f_{xx} = 0$ from start starting guess, and someone came along and said "oh you can solve that by just iterating $f_{n+1} = f_n + \alpha (f_n)_{xx}$" that would seem pretty magical. Why does it work? Does it work for any equation? For which does it not work?

Comment: The fixed-point scheme does only work for the discretized problem, in the continuous problem the differentiation operator is always unbounded, so the argument does not work. But yes, in general, if you want to solve $f(x)=0$ you can make it into fixed-point form $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)=x_n+α(x_n)f(x_n)$ and determine that $α(x)$ is best close to $-f'(x)^{-1}$. Here that would mean to employ the Green kernel or some suitable approximation of it. This could be approximated using implicit Euler or Crank-Nicholson for the heat equation.